# SQL query find if that record is first record on matching condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

##### Example database table

`requests`

```
  | id | user_id | status   | requested_by_id | position | order_id |
  | 1  | 1       | pending  |                 |          | 1        |
  | 3  | 2       | pending  | 2               | 1        | 1        |
  | 4  | 3       | pending  | 2               | 2        | 1        |
  | 5  | 2       | pending  | 2               | 3        | 2        |
```

From above table I want to find all records that are pending request for given `user_id`

##### criteria:

- If `requested_by_id` and `position` is `null` and `status` is `pending` then the result should include in the result.
- If `requested_by_id` and `position` is `not null` and `status` is `pending` then if given user id is the first request for the same `order_id` (i.e `where order_id = :id order by position asc LIMIT 1`), then it should include in result otherwise it should not.

Example:

**User Id: 1**, should return:

```
  | id | user_id | status   | requested_by_id | position | order_id |
  | 1  | 1       | pending  |                 |          | 1        |
```

**User id: 2** should return 2 results:

```
  | id | user_id | status   | requested_by_id | position | order_id |
  | 3  | 2       | pending  | 2               | 1        | 1        |
  | 5  | 2       | pending  | 2               | 3        | 2        |
```

**User id 3** should return 0 results, because user id: 2 is the first pending approver for order_id 1 because it has non null requested_by_id and position 1, whereas user_id 3 has position of 2.

> Also NOTE THAT, as per the requirement criteria, if requests.id = 2 had status = 'approved', then all three user should have return 1 result each users. Meaning user id 1 will have row for request with id 1. User id 2 should have request with id 5 and user id 3 should have request with id 4.

Please Let me know if something is not clear, thanks.

**UPDATE**

I have a very basic query right now which returns all the result at the moment:

```
select *
from requests
where status = 'pending' AND requested_by_id IS NULL AND position IS NULL
-- I need a OR query to find record if requested_by_id is NOT NULL and status = 'pending' AND position is the min(position) in above case position 1 has pending request for user id 2
AND user_id = 2;
```

**Update 2**

```
select *
from requests
where status = 'pending'
AND requested_by_id IS NULL
AND position IS NULL
AND (
  requested_by_id IS NULL OR (
    requested_by_id IS NOT NULL AND (
      select r1.user_id 
      from requests r1
      AND r1.status = 0
      order by position asc LIMIT 1
    ) = 2
  )
)
AND user_id = 2;
```

Please suggest me, if I can improve this query further. thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you have tried please publish what you have so far..

Comment: Updated question and added query @P.Salmon

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms